# Select Existing Sheet

Tags: apache-poi

How do I select an existing sheet that I know the name of the sheet?  I want to append code to a sheet but in different columns.  In the code below, I am referring to the wb.creatsheet("Summary") line.

```
def sql_a = """

SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY WHERE UPPER(MOPACTIVITY.mopid) = 'JONATHAN MORNINGSTAR'
ORDER BY MOPACTIVITY.MOPID

    """

def date = new Date() 
def dts = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") 
File file = new File('X:/CCG/' + dts + ' CCG REPORT.xls')              
file.write("")

Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook()

try {
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Summary")
                sheet.setColumnWidth(0,8.43 * 256)
                int rowNum = 0

    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum)
    Cell cellMOPID = row.createCell(0)

                cellMOPID.setCellStyle(headerStyle)

                cellMOPID.setCellValue("")

                db.eachRow(sql_a) {

                                rowNum++
                                row = sheet.createRow(rowNum)
                                cellMOPID = row.createCell(0)

                                cellMOPID.setCellValue(it.MOPID)

                                file.append(it.MOPID + "\n")
                }   

} catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.toString()) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [JavaDocs for the Workbook interface](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html), you'll see that as well as [createSheet(String)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createSheet%28java.lang.String%29) there's also a [getSheet(String)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getSheet%28java.lang.String%29) method. Call that with your existing sheet name, and you'll get the existing sheet to work with

Your code will want to be something like:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xls"));
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Summary");
// Read and add to the existing sheet here!
```